# Join two similar tables with some different columns

Tags: sql

We have two tables, one showing results from a process and one showing errors or other events. Some of the columns can be combined, while others can't. There are unique columns in each table, so I can't use a UNION ALL.

For example I have the following columns (there are more but you get the idea):

```
EventID | DateTime | Station | ErrMsg

ResultID | DateTime | Station | MatNum | SerialNum
```

So the first three columns in each example table could be combined, but the others would need their own column.

The idea here is to overlay the results with the errors and order by the date/time so that we can see if there are any process steps causing errors.

I've tried different joins, unions, ect, but didn't quite get what I want.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why you can't join them a take all columns you need from both? `events.*, results.*`, or name columns you need, of course, instead of taking all using `*`.

Comment: How many columns are there?

Comment: Provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I wanted columns with the same data type to be in the same column to make sorting efficient, but the other ones could be different. This table isn't really for sorting or managing data, just to overlay the two so we can see when errors are occurring in the process.

There's a ton of columns, and I'm not sure if I can share the data because it's from work. The answers work out so I'm going to give those a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first three columns have compatible data types and the others don't you'l need to separate columns for each of the incompatible columns.  I'd also add a discriminator column so you can immediately tell which data source the row came from:

```
Select
'E' src, EventID,  DateTime, Station, NULL,   NULL,      ErrMsg
from Events
UNION ALL
Select
'R' src, ResultID, DateTime, Station, MatNum, SerialNum, NULL
from Results
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware you could stick "NULL" in for the column name if there isn't a match in the second table. I also like the idea of adding the table names, I was hoping for a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This would technically work, if this is really how you want to have your output...

```
Select
EventID, DateTime, Station, ErrMsg, NULL
from Events
UNION ALL
Select
ResultID, DateTime, Station, MatNum, SerialNum
from Results
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware you could stick "NULL" in for the column name if there isn't a match in the second table.